# VC9 display details about the exception that just occured

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, exception, visual-c++

I'm debugging an application in visual C++ 2008 express. An exception occurs so the debugger breaks and waits for my instructions.

How do I view the details of that exception, as an object, just like other stack level objects in the `auto` and `local` windows.

For instance, in my immediate case its a std:exception. So chances are it has some sort of a string associate with it as the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just press F5 (Continue), the exception that was just caught is re-displayed so you can inspect it.

Comment: when I tried that, I would just get an access exception, from then on.